# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options executed every build

Tags: catkin, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I noticed that in my project every node with dynamic_reconfigure is rebuilt even if there is no file change. Is this a known behaviour of catkin? Is there anyway to prevent it?

Thanking you,
Benzun

Edit: I thought I solved this issue but everytime i run dynamic reconfigure the headers are created again in the folder /devel/include/package_name.

I am using ros hydro on Ubuntu 12.04. I am just building the dynamic_reconfigure tutorial from http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile

Everytime i run the build i get the following

Generating dynamic reconfigure files from cfg/Tutorial.cfg: /home/bpwiselybabu/drc_workspace/devel/include/dynamic_tutorials/TutorialConfig.h /home/bpwiselybabu/drc_workspace/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamic_tutorials/cfg/TutorialConfig.py

Even though I have not edited the cfg/Tutorial.cfg file

This does not happen with ros messages though.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165426/generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options-executed-every-build/) by [Benny](https://answers.ros.org/users/2216/benny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 132 on 2014-05-15

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-05-21**:
This is not a known issue. If you want more help to figure out what is happening for you you might want to provide more information: Which version of ROS are you using? For which package do you experience the issue? What commands do you invoke, what is the actual output, what the expected?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-05-24**:
Without more information, I don't see how anyone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen this happen when the class name that is generated doesn't match the file name that generated it.

This is noted in the tutorial that you link to:

"NOTE: The third parameter should be equal to the cfg file name, without extension. Otherwise the libraries will be generated in every build, forcing a recompilation of the nodes which use them."

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on 2015-10-22**:
I had the same issue on ubuntu 14.04 / ros indigo. This solved it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We had the same problem but we fixed it by adding _catkin in the following line in the cfg file:

```
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *
```

I had converted an old package to catkin and had missed that you needed _catkin here.

---

Originally posted by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) with karma: 1339 on 2014-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benny](https://answers.ros.org/users/2216/benny/) on 2014-05-22**:
Similar issue I was upgrading an existing package in catkin. but I already made the change you suggested, yet it occurs.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2014-05-22**:
I just tested to remove _catkin and then it re-generated the dynamic_reconfigure files each time I run catkin_make. I tested it on Hydro.

**Comment by [RaminYT](https://answers.ros.org/users/41903/raminyt/) on 2019-05-29**:
This solved my problem (the parameter name was already matching the cfg name). Thanks a lot :)